# How to make 7-segment display count up ?

Tags: timer, 555, 7segmentdisplay, counter, decoder

[image]

I've connect 7447 decoder and 74193 counter as shown in the picture but I have not used 555 timer yet.

Is there any way to test the circuit before using 555 ? 
I've connected the pins (up and down) of the counter to the positive terminal, and then disconnected them several times. ( I just wanted to do the function of 555 manually ). but the display did not count up... why ?? I want to test the circuit before putting 555 ?

one more thing, what are the pins A,B,C and D of the counter ? why do we connect them to the ground ?
and also what Bo,Co and load are?

this is the datasheet of the counter :
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls193.pdf

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Hi Warren,
No,It is not a homework. but I just play with electronics because I'm a student of the faculty of Engineering(Electric department )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pins A, B, C, and D are inputs.  If you want to load the counter with a particular value, you set these pins appropriately, then take the "Load" input low briefly.  If you are not using this function, the pins can be left unconnected.

The "CLR" input must be held LOW for the counter to work, and pulsed high to clear the counter.

Bipolar TTL (74LSxxx) inputs appear High when not connected, but when used with switched, it is good practice to pull them high with a 4.7K (or so) resistor to +5 volts, and use the switch to pull the input to ground for a Low input.

With CMOS parts (anything with a "C" in the middle of the part number), unused inputs must always be connected to either +5 or ground, as needed to make the part work as desired.  Switched inputs can be connected either as above, or with a resistor to ground, and switch to +5V.

The UP and DOWN inputs must be held high when inactive, and pulsed low to increment or decrement the counter.

Comment: There are CMOS logic families without "C", for example LV or LVX.

Answer (score 0):

The inputs A B C D and Load# are for loading arbitrary initial value. Bo and Co are borrow-out and carry-out and are used for chaining of multiple counters. To use Up and Down inputs manually, connect them to ground with a 10k pull-down resistor and place a button between VCC and the input.

Edit: to increment or decrement the counter, hold one button pressed and push the other one repeatedly.

Edit: 10k pull-down is indeed too big, to keep voltage under 0.8V at -0.4mA input current, 1k or lower is needed.

Edit: He could as well use switch to ground without pullup, but that would not be that comfortable because the inputs are rising-edge-triggered.

Comment: He appears to be using TTL parts - a 10K pulldown won't do much with that.  He needs a switch to ground, and a pull-up is a good idea, but probably not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that when you say you "connected the pins (up and down) of the counter to the positive terminal, and then disconnected them several times" that you connected a wire to either the UP or DOWN pin and touched it against the power rail.

The UP and DOWN pins are digital inputs. They expect to see digital high signal and digital low signals. The wire you were holding in your hand is floating (when you weren't touching the power rail) and is completely undefined in the digital world. So you were not creating the same signal a 555 would. To fix this, just put pull-down resistors on UP and DOWN. Something like <strike>10k</strike> 1k resistors connecting each pin to ground will work. That way, when the wire is floating, the pull-down resistor will make the digital input look like a digital low.

The A, B, C, and D pins are for pre-loading a value into the counter. If, for some reason, you always wanted to have the counter start at the number 3, you would present the binary value 0011 on those four pins. Namely, you would hard-wire A and B to a digital high and C and D to a digital low. Since you appear to always want the counter to start at 0, you are hard-wiring all four pins to ground so the counter is preset to start at 0.

Co and Bo are overflow and underflow flags, respectively. When your counter counts up to 15 and overflows back to 0, the Co pin goes high. Similarly, when the counter counts down to 0 and underflows to 15, the Bo pin goes high. This is an optional feature for you to employ in your circuit if you have a need. Based on your simple circuit, it doesn't look like you have a need to know when there is an overflow or underflow. Since these pins are digital outputs, it is safe to leave them unconnected if you don't use them.

The Load pin is pulsed low (by you) once at the beginning of your count to load in the preset value defined by pins A, B, C, and D. It is not clear to me from the datasheet if it is absolutely necessary to pulse the Load pin before you may begin counting. My guess would be that it is necessary.

EDIT: Agree with Venny. A 10k pull-down is too large for inputs on the 'LS193 part. A 1k would work.[image]

Comment: Traditionally, with bipolar TTL logic (plain 74xxx or 74LSxx and others) we would use a switch between input and ground, and a pull-up resistor just to be sure an open switch was really received as a high. (Speaking as someone who was around when 74LS was "New, Improved!")

Comment: @Peter, I admit I had to stare at the "equivalent of inputs" graphic for a minute when I first noticed it after posting my answer. I agree a pull-up resistor and a switch to ground (or tapping ground with a free hanging wire, as the OP seems to be trying to do) is probably better suited.